# How to change rtsp streaming size in c#?

Tags: c#, opencv

I am using rtsp streaming in c# using below code
However, the code below plays back the original size of the video.
I want to resize the video
How can I increase the size of my video?

```
video = new VideoCapture();
video.Open(rtspUrl);

using (Mat image = new Mat())
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (!video.Read(image))
        {
            Cv2.WaitKey();
        }
        if (!image.Empty())
        {
            Bitmap bmp = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);

            pbStream.Image = bmp;
        }
        if (Cv2.WaitKey(1) >= 0)
            break;
        if (isRun == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
video = null;
```

Comment: I solved it by resizing the bitmap

Comment: mfc? winforms? wpf? not an opencv problem. opencv merely decodes the stream for you.